# Where can I find good link exchange programs and forums?

Tags: links, backlinks

googling didnt worked in finding good link exchange programs.Has anyone of you tried an automatic link exchange program?My sites page rank has fallen from 3 to 1.Please help

Comment: This isn't going to solve your PR problem and most likely will hurt your site. I'd recommend against it.

Comment: @John:If backlinks don't make PR and updating doesn't make PR than what does make PR?

Comment: Organic backlinks give you PR; buying links or doing link exchanges do not--and especially not link from the type of sites that link exchange forums are usually used by. Sites with unique high quality content don't need to purchase their backlinks with cash or with reciprocal links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't afford to do [link exchanges](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/business/marketing/why-you-cant-afford-to-link-exchange) and I can [prove it](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/business/tools/link-exchange-cost-calculator). I explain in detail on my website, but simply put, when you factor in time for discovery, contact, failure, success, implementation, and maintenance, link exchanging is too expensive. It doesn't scale and it has low if any return on investment. What's worse, you can't measure the ROI either.

You're far better off:

- Creating content that people *want*
  to link to.
- Making it easy for people to share
  your content.
- Getting the technical aspects of your
  page right.
- Doing keyword research so that you
  target the right phrases.
- Expanding your own site so that you
  have more pages that you control to
  link from (they count too).
- Building a community.
- Planning and then executing a content
  and marketing strategy.
- Actually paying for targeted,
  measurable advertising.
- Streamlining and optimizing your
  entire sales funnel.
- Working on your conversion rates once
  people get to your target page.
- Using upsells and cross-promotions to
  increase your profit margins.
- Retaining and reselling to existing
  customers.
- Systemizing and then either
  automating or delegating your
  successful business practices.

As a part of the successful SEO tactics pie, link exchanging isn't even one of the ingredients. What's more, SEO is only a very small part in the overall picture. Don't lose sight of that.

Comment: +1, fahad, for being willing to learn. It sometimes helps to take a step back to examine if what is being promoted as successful actually works. Link exchanges may have worked at one time, but the search engines have long since caught on. Plus, it's just too expensive and many view link exchange requests as spam, which can hurt your business.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your PR drop. It could be due to number of factors. Like old links vanishing, PR of pages linking to your pages going down, etc. Also, ensure your content is regularly updated.

Comment: Yes,the site was not uploaded for almost a year.Now started to work again

Comment: Content has nothing to do with PR. PR is about link popularity only. Also, this should either be a comment or added to your previous answer.